# How to navigate to another page in Immediate Window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, navigation, immediate-window

I'm trying to navigate to a page with the help of `Immediate Window` in Visual Studio. I'm using Windows Phone 8.1 Emulators. Normally when writing things like `x = 1;` etc. does work very well. But when I'm trying to use navigation service,

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ErrorPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
```

But it does not let me to do so with error message as `The expression cannot be evaluated while in run mode.`

So I'm wondering if there is any option to let the navigation service work?

Note: The project is in TFS and I cannot check-out the page(neither XAML or code behind), so I have no option to add a temp button to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Get the latest Version from TFS by Setting up a local Workspace and choosing "Get Latest". (How are you even able to compile?) [Click Me](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx)

Second: If the Immediate Windows says that it can't, it can't. There is no work-around to that. Some things do not work in IW, like Lambda Expressions ([but it's finally coming :D !](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx)) and NavigationService.

Addendum: I just googled a bit and there is a VS-Extension on Codeplex called "[Extended Immediate Window](https://extendedimmediatewin.codeplex.com/)". Maybe this is going to help you. I don't know it personally.

Comment: sorry I wanted to say check-out, not check-in. So there's no problem with compiling or getting latest.

Comment: Please see my Addendum

Comment: nah, unfortunately it doesn't load the project as it is for vs2008.. Thank you for helping. I think I'll wait for VS2015 or the colleague to check-in..

Comment: There seems to be a followup Project for 2010 under extendedimmediate2.codeplex.com. Anyway thanks for the vote.